# Axios doesn't send post requset on iphone safari or chrome app

Tags: ios, reactjs, mobile, axios

I made reactjs project using create-react-app on front-end and python/django on back-end and I deployed it on heroku.

when I open my chrome browser and login on my laptop, It works fine.
but If i try to login on my iphone safari or chrome app, it doesn't work.

I use axios to submit login form data on http post request.
below are my login saga

```
export function* login({ username, password, history }){
  const params = {
    url: API_URL + '/token/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { username, password }
  }
  const { request, response } = yield call(api, params)

  if(request.status === 400){

    yield put(doLoginFail(Object.values(response.data).map(a=>a[0])))
  }else{
    yield put(doLoginSuccess(username))
    yield history.push('/calendar')
  }
}
```

I've looked up my heroku app logs, and there are no logs by login attempt on iphone. (but when I login on my laptop, it shows updated logs.)

So I guess axios doesn't send any request?

I used
 - axios 0.18.0
 - React 16.4
 - Python 3.6.5
 - Django 2.0.6
 - Node.js 8.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry It was a stupid mistake. I set up wrong url for axios.
It works fine on safari and chrome app.